# Spark - how to rename a column in orc file (not table)

Tags: apache-spark, hive

We a hive ORC table which is being populated with spark jobs. The problem is hive table has a column name "ABC". however while loading on the job, we loaded ORC file with column "XYZ".

**problem:**
some of the orc file has "ABC" column and some of the orc file has "XYZ" column. And hive schema has "ABC" column.

How do I merge both these columns into "ABC" using spark?

**we have around 100 such big tables.**

**current Solution**

1. Create tempoary hive table.
2. insert records from main table where abc is not null
3. Change column name to xyz in main table and load temp table where xyz is null
4. Change column name back to "ABC"
5. insert overwrite main table with temp table.

Comment: Can't you create a view instead of this complete process?

Comment: what do you mean by view ?

Comment: `CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT ( coalesce(abc, xyz) as abc) FROM table_name` something like this ? Will it help downstream users?

Comment: @PiyushPatel "xyz" column does not exist in table. it's only in ORC file

Comment: @PiyushPatel I could add this table.. but then there is no way to remove that column in hive